# Why does an assignment from an rvalue reference type not invoke the move assignment operator?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct my_struct {
    void func(std::string&& str) {
        str_ = str;
    }

    std::string str_;
};

int main() {
    my_struct s;
    std::string str("Hello");

    s.func(std::move(str));

    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    std::cout << s.str_ << std::endl;    
}
```

Why do I need an extra `std::move` in `my_struct::func` in order to invoke the move assignment operator of `std::string`? What would the extra `std::move` exactly do? I thought it would just cast the given type to its rvalue reference counterpart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `str_ = str;`, `str` is a named variable.  That means inside your function `str` is an lvalue, not an rvalue.  This means copy assignment is used and not move assignment.

What you need to do is get `str` back to an rvalue and you can do that with `std::move` like

```
str_ = std::move(str);
```

Comment: What I recently learned from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779079/why-does-c11-have-implicit-moves-for-value-parameters-but-not-for-rvalue-para is that `std::move` actually generates an xvalue which is a special rvalue.

Answer (score 3):

```
void func(std::string&& str) {
    str_ = str;
}
```

should be

```
void func(std::string&& str) {
    str_ = std::move(str);
}
```

as `str` has a name, and so is a lvalue.